# Even numbers has the form $a+b$ where $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures, sums-of-squares

Conjecture:
All even numbers $n>2$ can be written $n=a+b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb N^+$ and 
$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\in\mathbb P$.

Is tested for $n<10,000,000$.

This conjecture is related to and maybe dependent on  [Any odd number is of form $a+b$ where $a^2+b^2$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386860/any-odd-number-is-of-form-ab-where-a2b2-is-prime).

Comment: Equivalently, for every even $n=2k$, there is $a<n$ such that $\dfrac{2a^2-2an+n^2}2 = a^2-2ak +2k^2 \in \Bbb P$

Comment: Equivalently, for every $k>1$ there is $a<2k$ such that $(a-k)^2+k^2\in\mathbb{P}$. Then without loss of generality we may restrict to $a<k$, and the question comes down to asking whether there is a prime in the sequence $\{k^2+c^2:\ 0<c<k\}$ for every $k>1$.

Comment: Isn't this (like the linked question) a special case of the Bateman-Horn conjecture?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I can't see that.