# $\{a+b|a,b\in\mathbb N^+\wedge ma^2+nb^2\in\mathbb P\}=\{k>1|\gcd(k,m+n)=1\}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, conjectures, sums-of-squares

Conjecture:
$\{a+b|a,b\in\mathbb N^+\wedge ma^2+nb^2\in\mathbb P^{>2}\}=\{k>2|\gcd(k,m+n)=1\}$ 
if $m,n\in \mathbb N^+$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

This is a generalization of [Any odd number is of form $a+b$ where $a^2+b^2$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386860/any-odd-number-is-of-form-ab-where-a2b2-is-prime). Perhaps the generalization will spread some light of what is going on?

There is a perfect match of the formula for all tests I've done.

---

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280123/the-set-of-numbers-ab-such-that-ma2nb2-is-prime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
$$ m=1,n=91, a+b \neq 3  $$
although
$$ \gcd(1,91) = 1,  $$
$$ \gcd(3,92) = 1. $$
$$ 2^2 + 91 \cdot 1^2 = 95 $$
$$ 1^2 + 91 \cdot 2^2 = 365 $$

---

Looking at what I did, taking $m=1,$ we can take any $n \equiv 1 \pmod {30}$ with the same outcome. So, with $n=31,$ our two numbers that are not prime  are $35$ and $125.$

Comment: Yes, it seems like a correction of the formula is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer ...

Noting $A=\{a+b \mid a,b\in \mathbb{N}^{+} \wedge ma^2+nb^2 \in \mathbb{P}^{>2}\}$ and $B=\{k > 1 \mid \gcd(k,m+n)=1\}$ **it's easy to show $A \subset   B$.**

1. $a,b\in \mathbb{N}^{+} \Rightarrow a+b > 1$
2. Now we need to show that $\gcd(a+b,m+n)=1$. Let's assume contrary $\gcd(a+b,m+n)=d>1$ then $a \equiv -b \pmod{d}$ and $m \equiv -n \pmod{d}$. Or $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod{d}$ and $m \equiv -n \pmod{d}$. Or $ma^2 \equiv -nb^2 \pmod{d} \Rightarrow d \mid ma^2 +nb^2$, so $d$ divides a prime $>2$ and $d \ne ma^2 +nb^2$ since $a+b\leq ma^2 +nb^2=d\leq a+b$, leading to $a+b=ma^2 +nb^2=2 \notin A$,  a contradiction, thus $d=1$.